# Magento if product configurable show options

Tags: php, html, magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I need to show product options on my related products:

In list.phtml for every configurable products i show its options (option means an attribute like colour) with this code:

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'): ?> 
   <?php echo $this->getOptionsHtml($_product); ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Result: nothing!!!

What is wrong here? Why in related.phtml is not working?

**getOptionsHtml** - This function is from Belvg ColorSwatchPro extension.

```
<?php
class Belvg_ColorSwatchPro_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{       
    public function getOptionsHtml($_product)
    {    die('sss');
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Belvg_ColorSwatchPro_Block_Product_List_Options',
            'product_list_options',
            array('template' => 'colorswatch/product/list/options.phtml'
        ));

        $block->setProduct($_product);

        return $block->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no definition of such function as `getOptionsHtml` in standard Magento(checked for Magento 1.8). Where this function is defined?

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi . I know but why is working on the other pages? homelist.phtml and catalog category page?

Comment: Maybe those templates are assigned to the blocks which are provided by some third party extension. Just make a search in your code for `function getOptionsHtml(` and you should find the block where it is defined.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi . Yes I found that function.

<?php
class Belvg_ColorSwatchPro_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{  
 public function getOptionsHtml($_product)
 {  die('sss');
  $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
   'Belvg_ColorSwatchPro_Block_Product_List_Options',
   'product_list_options',
   array('template' => 'colorswatch/product/list/options.phtml'
  ));
  
  $block->setProduct($_product);
  
  return $block->toHtml();
 }
}

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi that function is from Belvg ColorSwatchPro extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I will try to explain you why it is in this way.

All templates in magento are assigned to some blocks. For example in your case `list.phtml` uses `Belvg_ColorSwatchPro_Block_Product_List` block. So if inside template you call construction `$this->getOptionsHtml($_product);` it means that you call the method of `Belvg_ColorSwatchPro_Block_Product_List` block.

But when you use `$this->getOptionsHtml($_product)` in related.phtml it doesn't work because this template is assigned to block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related` which has no method `getOptionsHtml`.

To make that workable, I can advise you the easiest way. Inside related.phtml template  instead of

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'): ?> 
    <?php echo $this->getOptionsHtml($_product); ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

use

```
<?php if($_item->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Belvg_ColorSwatchPro_Block_Product_List_Options',
        'product_list_options',
        array('template' => 'colorswatch/product/list/options.phtml'
    ));

    $block->setProduct($_item);

    echo $block->toHtml();
}?>
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Now I understand the way how to play with blocks from third party extension like ColorSwatchPro.

Comment: Your answer is super - awesome. It worked like a charm. Thank you again.

Comment: I have another problem because of this now. You know, I have color swatches on product page and below I added related products with color swatches using your snippet. Both color swatches are visible now. But color swatches for main product are not switching. Any idea why? Is there any issue if i used colorswatch/product/list/options.phtml two times in same page? I don't have any console error.

Comment: Yes it could be some javascript issues because of using `colorswatch/product/list/options.phtml` twice even if there are no console errors. I did not use this extension so I cannot say you for 100% sure. So the best way would be to investigate javascript code in template.

Comment: All i found is this js 

<script>var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>); </script>

This is within view.phtml.(Product page.) If I remove this, Configurable product does not have swatches anymore. But the swatches of related products are working... very strange. In options.phtml I didn't found this js.